# Counting the email and phone more than 3 and showing the output as _id,email count,phone count

Tags: mongodb

I want to get _id,count of email,count of phone and filter condition is documents  having email or phone count more than 3.
Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the sample document format:

```
{

    "_id" : "23243pbfg1-47a9-9d98-23423hffngfkl",

     "key" : {
             "phone" : [
                     "1234567890",
                     "9999999999",
                     "9888888888",
             ],
             "email" : [
                     "abc@test.com",
                     "xyz@test.com",
                     "test@test.com",
                     "qwert@test.com"
             ]
     }
```

Comment: `.find({ "$or": [{ "key.phone.3": { "$exists": true } }, { "key.email.3": { "$exists": true } }] })`. Which basically asks "if the third index position ( 4th element ) is actually present", and that means the length is greater than 3.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. It worked. :)

Comment: If i want to get the _id,email count,phone count of a document. Any suggestions.